# Create function with 3 parameters - beginningyear, endingyear and month

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

The function then calculates and returns the total sale
 for the requested month of the requested years. If there was
 no sale for the requested period, returns 0

I tried this function, but I don't understand what to do next.

I don't think, the logic is correct.

```
  CREATE Function sales
     (@BeginningYear int, @EndingYear int, @Month int)
    RETURNS @DateList TABLE (StartDate int, EndDate int, Month int,TotalSales int)
    AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @SUM int = 0
    SELECT SUM(TotalDue) From Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    Where CAST(ORDERDATE as month) = @Month AND CAST(ORDERDATE as year) = @BeginningYear
    AND CAST(ORDERDATE as year)= @EndingYear
    Group by OrderDate
    RETURN;
    END
```

[image: Screenshot of the table]

Comment: Are you trying to return a table or just the sum?

Comment: @Ankur just the total sale for the requested month of the requested years. I need to use the Sales.SalesOrderHeader table to calculate the TotalSale using the TotalDue column

Comment: So for example, if I pass 2005, 2010, January. Then you want the total for the January month starting from 2005 to 2010, correct? OR do you need the total sale of each year in a seperate row?

Comment: Yes. Total for the January month starting from 2005 to 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CREATE Function sales
     (@BeginningYear int, @EndingYear int, @Month int)
    RETURNS Numeric (12,4)
    AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @SUM Numeric (12,4) = 0
    SELECT @SUM = SUM(TotalDue) From Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    Where CAST(ORDERDATE as month) = @Month AND CAST(ORDERDATE as year) Between @BeginningYear
    AND @EndingYear
    RETURN @SUM;
    END
```

Comment: this show incorrect syntax near '@SUM'

The select statement

SELECT SUM(TotalDue) into @SUM From Sales.SalesOrderHeader